# Getting protected values from object Facebook API (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, object, protected

How to get the protected values from the object below FB returns in their API?

```
Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken Object
(
    [value:protected] => AAAAAAA
    [expiresAt:protected] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-30 19:27:26.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

)
```

I tried like this: `$var->value` or `$var->expiresAt->date` but doesn't work.

Comment: It's an object with a class definition.... the class will provide methods to get those properties if there's valid reason for having access to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook API encapsulates its properties, so you need to use the getters. For example, you can get the [`expiresAt`](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/2f9639c15ae043911f40ffe44080b32bac2c5280/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessToken.php#L78) property with the getter:

```
var_dump($accessToken->getExpiresAt()->format("d/m/Y H:i:s")); // string(19) "30/11/2017 16:43:11"
```

The same goes for [value](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/2f9639c15ae043911f40ffe44080b32bac2c5280/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessToken.php#L134) and the rest of the properties.

Comment: I don't actually need to reformat, is there a way to get the `expiresAt` as is? And what about the `value` aka. the token? How do I get that?

Comment: Just delete the `format()` call, `$expires = $accessToken->getExpiresAt()`. For the value, `$value = $accessToken->getValue();`

Comment: I tired `$accessToken->getExpiresAt()` without format, cause I don't need to format it. And it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't quite understand you, when you say "as is", do you mean you need the `DateTime` instance, or you need the date formatted like in your example output? Because getting just `getExpiresAt()` will give you a `DateTime` instance, and you *need* to format it in order to get a string.

Comment: `$accessToken->getValue()` works. `$accessToken->getExpiresAt()` doesn't work without the format part. I don't need to reformat anything cause its going straight to a DB.

Comment: Use `$accessToken->getExpiresAt()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u")` to get the exact same format from your example. As I said in my previous comment, you *need* to format it to get a string.